# root-artifact.xml does not automatically generate when create CApp project (wso2 carbon studio v2.0.1)

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I installed wso2 carbon studio 2.0.1 (ref: http://wso2.org/project/developer-studio/2.0.1/docs/install_guide.html, https://wso2.org/jira/browse/TOOLS-739), but root-artifact.xml does not automatically generate when CApp project creating. And a pom.xml file has been created over here. Could I build a root-artifact.xml manually?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSO2 Developer Studio 2.0.0 and later versions no longer uses the root-artifact.xml and the previous C-App model.

There are fundamental changes between Dev Studio 2.x.x versions and 1.0.x versions such as dropping root-artifact.xml, introducing pom.xml and using pom.xml for metadata management, new project structure, etc.

So it is not a bug in Dev Studio 2.0.0 but rather how it is designed.

Comment: Thanks! I also found the updated documents, and built my first car project in wso2 carbon studio v2.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

well, wso2 carbon studio v1.0.14 is working. It seems a new bug for v2.0.1.